# mongodump file corruption on virtual machine

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, database

Today I am doing mongodump to backup a db with around 2GB in file size but I only have around 600 mb in the dumped files.  There is no error messages on the mongodump operation and later I found out that some documents are missing. And if not because of the huge difference in file size that I wouldn't know the dump is not successful.

Is there a standard way to check if the dumped files are correct?

p.s: It seems that I can use `db.stats()` to check the original db info, and then mongorestore the dumped db and do `db.stats()` to compare the total file size. And the two file sizes would be the same (am I right)?

p.s: Also if my VM has memory 500 mb can it successfully dump a 2GB file?

Comment: How do you tell it's corrupted? Dumps are usually smaller than the DB on disc, as they do not contain index data e.g., which can simply be regenerated.

Comment: I did mongorestore on my local machine and see missing documents. (misses like 60%..). VM memory is 500mb and dumped bson for that collection is only 600mb..

Answer (score 2):

You have a database with a 2GB file size, but MongoDB allocates data files in chunks (like 2GB) and may not fill them for some time.  You may well only have 600MB of data in your database (see [db.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.stats/) for some guidance). You should also note that indexes will not be dumped out, only their definitions for rebuilding on a restore, so the removal of these will impact your dump size.  Since you have no errors, I suspect you have a perfectly valid dump here, which reflects the amount of data actually present in your 2GB of files.

> if my VM has memory 500 mb can it successfully dump a 2GB file?

Yes, though it will be faster if all of the data can fit in memory

Comment: but is there a limit on the file size 500mb memory can dump?

Comment: no, it will simply have to page in memory from disk more while dumping because the data cannot fit into memory - there is no limit

Comment: I see. Basically I just ssh inside the instance and do mongodump regardless of whether there are db connections or not. (because we're not in production yet but don't know if there will be any difference when dumping on production). Also I didn't reboot before I mongodump so the free memory could be already really low. I guess I'll come back to this maybe next month when I would be doing backup again.!

Comment: when you run mongodump, it will walk the _id index (paging that into memory) and use that to dump the actual data (then paging that into memory too).  It's actually a quick way to pre-heat your data set if you use _id. Therefore if the _id index and data fit into, and especially if they are already in, memory it will dump out nice and fast. If they do not fit, then the later data will be paged in, earlier data paged out, and the dump will be slower as a result, but will still complete even though data exceeds memory

Comment: is it a best practice to remove all indexes before dumping the data?

Comment: no, removing indexes will not impact mongodump, as it only dumps out the index definitions, which are tiny.  You can skip doing the index scan and force a table scan, but that can be dangerous, and is not likely to be any faster: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--forceTableScan

Comment: btw. can you do something like db.stats() to dumped file directly? (without mongorestore first)?

Comment: no, they are not in database files, they are just a series of bson encoded documents, you cannot run any MongoDB commands on them until they are restored

Comment: I see. then basically there is no way to know if the entire db is dumped correctly before we mongorestore the db right? which is basically what happened before..

Comment: I have updated my post a bit. Is the above the right way to check your backup files? (even though there's no mongodump errors whatsoever?)